# div function inside another div function

Tags: php, html, function, block

Is it possible in php to make the second div appears inside the first one instead of getting two separated divs ?
I would like to make a php dom system but I'm stuck with this problem.

This is the HTML I get when the page returns :

```
<div style="width:
                50px;
            height:
                30px;
            background-color:
                yellow;

                color:white
            ">
                blablabla
</div>
<div style="width:
                200px;
            height:
                50px;
            background-color:
                blue;

                color:white
            ">

</div>
```

This is the PHP code :

```
<? php

function genDiv($width, $height, $bgColor, $add, $content) {
    echo '
        <div style=\'width:
            '.$width.';
        height:
            '.$height.';
        background-color:
            '.$bgColor.';

            '.$add.'
        \'>
            '.$content.'
        </div>
    ';
}

$block = genDiv(
    '50px',
    '30px',
    'yellow',
    'color:white',
    'blablabla'
);
genDiv(
    '200px', 
    '50px',
    'blue',
    'color:white',
    $block
);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rewrite the function so it *returns* the HTML instead of echoing it out directly.

Then you can echo the result of the second call to the function.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `return` in your function, you `echo` st. directly.

```
function genDiv($width, $height, $bgColor, $add, $content) {
    return '
        <div style=\'width:
            '.$width.';
        height:
            '.$height.';
        background-color:
            '.$bgColor.';

            '.$add.'
        \'>
            '.$content.'
        </div>
    ';
}

$block = genDiv(
    '50px',
    '30px',
    'yellow',
    'color:white',
    'blablabla'
);
echo genDiv(
    '200px', 
    '50px',
    'blue',
    'color:white',
    $block
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can also use double quotes instead of single quotes.

I got the required output using this code.

```
<?php 
function genDiv($width,$height,$bgcolor,$add,$content)
{
    return "<div style='width $width; height:$height;
    background-color: $bgcolor; $add'>
    $content
    </div>";
}
$block = genDiv('50px','30px','orange','color:white','blablabla');
$content = genDiv('200px','50px','blue','color:white;padding-top:20px', $block);
echo $content; //required output. second div in first div
?>
```

I changed the yellow color and added padding for clear visibility.

Comment: Is your requirement achieved